# Check if contents of a DIV is only an Image

Tags: javascript

I have a div containing initially a loader image tag.

```
  <img src="/images/indicator_big.gif" style="display:block;margin:auto">
```

I want to check if the DIV contains only the loader image then the function should trigger an Ajax Request.

If i do some thing like `div.innerHTML` I get it as a string.

What will be the best way to test if the innerHTML is only a loader image?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or other lib?

Comment: surely you shouldn't rely on the contents of the div to decide whether you need to make the AJAX request or not?  Wouldn't it be better to have a boolean variable isLoaded that you can check instead?

Comment: Is this image solely used for showing whether a processing is loading or not? Might be easier to attach a `loading` class to the DIV instead and test for the presence of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will do what you ask, although I'm not sure the general approach is the best to be honest.

```
function hasOnlyImg(div) {
  if (div.children.length != 1)
    return false;
  return div.children[0].tagName == "IMG";
}
```

Comment: Just remember that some browser will output `tagName` as lower case, so you might want to adjust for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many elements are inside your element

```
var children = document.querySelector("#yourDiv > *");
if (children.length == 1 && children[0].tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
    //you only have one child in here, and that's an image
}
```

This will be 1 if it only contains your initial image.

Be wary of the browser support, though: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your 'style.display' of that loader image will change? You could just check for that?

```
function checkDiv(div,func) {
    var thisDiv = div;
    var imgLink = thisDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if (imgLink.length == 1 && imgLink[0].style.display !== "block") {
        func();
    }
}
checkDiv(document.getElementById("mydiv"),function() {
    //call ajax code
});
```

Or if you still would like to check the number of HTML tags within your div, just do something like:

```
var allDivTags = mydiv.getElementsByTagName("*");
if (allDivTags.length == 1 && allDivTags.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
    //only 1 html element exists in the div, and it's an image.
    //run code
}
```

Hope this helps.